# Can I move the services menu to the top of the contextual menu?

Tags: macos, services, context-menu

Is it possible to move the services section of the contextual menu from the bottom to the top?

Comment: This sounds impossible to do. Is it because you need to regularly access some services?

Comment: Yes, I use a services several times an hour and it would be nice if it was at the top of the menu.

Comment: Might be worth using keyboard shortcuts – see *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*. You can assign them to any service you want.

Comment: Alas, [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/) allows you to [change the order of the context menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnz4.png), but not the one of *Services*

Comment: Is this question about context menus or the submenus on the menu bar? (Or both?)

Comment: This question is referring to the contextual menu, not the menubar.